# Maximum number of outbound full relay connections

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, p2p

What is the maximum number of outbound full relay connections a bitcoin core full node can make?

I was assuming it's 8 but then realized we can add another 8 connections using `addnode` while reviewing this PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21710

So is it 16 or there is something else that I am missing which can be used to add more outbound full relay connections?

Also do we have any option to decrease the number of [MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/66fd3b28e85c167f3955b5603496daf8d91abcad/src/net.h#L64) below 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the maximum number of outbound full relay connections a bitcoin core full node can make?

Maximum number of outbound full relay connections is 16(8 automatic and 8 manual)

`MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS` 8 (automatic)

`MAX_ADDNODE_CONNECTIONS` 8 (manual)

*If you add 8 trusted nodes with `-connect` option, those will be the only nodes used for outbound full relay connections and nothing else.*

> Also do we have any option to decrease the number of MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS below 8?

No. And the developers who reviewed PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21815  think we don't need such option in Bitcoin Core.

Comment: When you provide `-connect`, those are the *only* nodes you connect to (it disables all other manual and automatic peer finding, including `-addnode`), so the limit is 16: 8 automatic ones, and 8 addnoded ones.

Comment: Thanks. Will edit the answer.