# Why variations in tor onion service incoming node identifcation formats?

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor, connection

With these bitcoin.conf parameters:

```
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
onlynet=onion
bind=127.0.0.1
externalip=[my 64-char code].onion
[plus 32 addnode=[onion address] entries]
```

I quickly get 18 outgoing connections to .onion addresses (and never more, even after 24+ hours?), and then after a while one or two incoming addresses identified like this:

```
127.0.0.1:57926 (node id: 40)
via 127.0.0.1:9050
```

or like this:

```
127.0.0.1:58152 (node id: 78)
via akuserwyfe5ehl6i.onion:32645
```

or like this:

```
127.0.0.1:58516 (node id: 189)
[that's it -- no "via"!]
```

What causes these node identification format variations?

Comment: Not sure how did you get 18 outgoing connections. Max automatic outbound connections are 8 and Max manual outbound connections are 8 so total 16 including manual: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/105927/

Comment: Plus up to 2 block-only connections gives 18.